# PowerShell - transpose results from a hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv, hashtable

I need to check the warranty of many servers, but the output returned by the module I found in https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/HPWarranty/2.6.2 seems to be a hashtable and the first column contains what I want to be my rows.

the script below will return this where every 5 rows the fields repeat - output1.csv:

> ## TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
>
> "Component","Codecount" 
> "SerialNumber","CZ36092P5H" 
> "ProductNumber","727021-B21" 
> "OverallEntitlementStartDate","2016-03-04" 
> "OverallEntitlementEndDate","2019-04-02" 
> "ActiveEntitlement","true" 
> "SerialNumber","CZ36092P5K" 
> "ProductNumber","727021-B21" 
> "OverallEntitlementStartDate","2016-03-04" 
> "OverallEntitlementEndDate","2019-04-02" 
> "ActiveEntitlement","true"

How can I transpose the output so that SerialNumber, ProductNumber, OverallEntitlementStartDate, OverallEntitlementEndDate and ActiveEntitlement    are the columns?

```
# variables
$dest_path = "C:\Scripts\HPE\HPWarranty"
$export_date = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ":", "-"}
$myScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
$transcriptPath = $dest_path + "\" + $myScriptName + "_transcript_" + $export_date + ".txt"
$csvPath = $dest_path + "\" + "hpe_list1.csv"

#Start transcript of script activities and set transcript location
start-transcript -append -path $transcriptPath | Out-Null

# import serials & part numbers to be processed
$csv_info = Import-Csv $csvPath

foreach ($line in $csv_info) {
    $hash = (Get-HPEntWarrantyEntitlement -ProductNumber $line.ProductNumber -SerialNumber $line.SerialNumber)
    &{$hash.getenumerator() |
        ForEach-Object {new-object psobject -Property @{Component = $_.name;Codecount=$_.value}}
    } | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\HPE\HPWarranty\output1.csv" -Append
}

# Stop Transcript
Stop-Transcript | Out-Null
```

hpe_list1.csv that the script processes contains the details for two servers:

> ProductNumber,SerialNumber 
> 727021-B21,CZ36092P5H 
> 727021-B21,CZ36092P5K

Comment: use the [Select-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176955.aspx) columns in a pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the output hashtable to a `[pscustomobject]`:

```
$WarrantyInfo = foreach ($line in $csv_info) {
    [pscustomobject](Get-HPEntWarrantyEntitlement -ProductNumber $line.ProductNumber -SerialNumber $line.SerialNumber)
}
$WarrantyInfo | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\HPE\HPWarranty\output1.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you BenH that's exactly what I needed!